# how to make a word or text tappable in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios4

In my App, I want a text or a string to be tapped which is there in the UITextView. after tapping it should connect to any url lets say, "www.google.com". The problem is, when I am tapping a text in UITextView, it doesn't get tapped. What should I do ? I am stuck since 2 days, please help me out.

Comment: Could you post the code you've already tried?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add button e.g. goToWebSiteButton on the top of your UITextView.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goToWebSiteButton;
```

Then synthesize it:

```
@synthesize goToWebSiteButton;
```

And then to add target to the button:

```
[goToWebSiteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToWebSite:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)goToWebSite:(id)sender event:(id)event{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@", @"www.google.com" ]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you tap on a UITextfield , it will get tapped as it is meant to enter any text by the user. If you want to connect to a url, simply add the `UIWebView` method to your `UITextfield` method.

It is better that after the user enters anything in the `UITextfield` let it be put into a`UILabel` or a`UIButton` and on its click or tap let it open the UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIWebView` and can make hyperlinks there.
Or you can use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel/) which can hold `NSAttributedString` 
Or you can have clear `UIButton`'s over the text where you want click.